# Measuring overlap between arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Given several arrays in Java (i'll be looping through keys currently stored in a HashMap), I want to be able to identify (based on the `boolean[]` keys currently stored) which indices are `true` in all of them, and which are `false`.

Example:

```
{true, true,false}
{true,false,false}
{true,false, false}
```

would yield index 0 as having all true values, and index 2 as having all false values.

One idea I have is to convert the boolean array to an array of ints, summing the values, and if the summed array index = numArrays, then it is True in all of them. Similarly, if the summed array index is 0, it is false in all of them.

Am not sure how to go about doing this in an efficient way (in java), letalone if this is a good method to achieve my desired result.

Is there a way to convert the array of booleans to ints? If not, is the easiest alternative to instantiate a new array of ints, and loop through the boolean array to populate the new array?

Comment: You essentially have a matrix or table (assuming they have the same number of columns).  You should be able to simply walk each column of each array and check it's results...

Comment: `0b110 & 0b100 & 0b100 == 0xb100` - bitwise AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all arrays will have same number of elements you can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] array1 = new boolean[] {true,true,false};
    boolean[] array2 = new boolean[] {true,false,false};
    boolean[] array3 = new boolean[] {true,false,false};
    boolean[] array4 = new boolean[] {true,false,false};

    compareAndPrintCommonIndicesForArrays(array1, array2, array3);
}

public static boolean compareAndPrintCommonIndicesForArrays(boolean[] ...arrays) {
    boolean result =true;
    boolean itemToCompare;
    int elementsToCompare = arrays[0].length;

    for(int itemIndex=0; itemIndex<elementsToCompare; itemIndex++) {
        result = true;
        itemToCompare = arrays[0][itemIndex];
        for(int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex<arrays.length;arrayIndex++) {
            if(itemToCompare != arrays[arrayIndex][itemIndex]) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        if(result) System.out.println(itemIndex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It prints:

`0
 2`

The code will traverse all indices and for every index it will compare elements from all the array at that index. If they are all same then the index is printed.

Comment: While technically correct, it's not going to scale well :p

Answer (score 2):

They are booleans, so I really don't know why you are thinking of converting them to integers and summing them up: it would be really easy but definitely useless.

So. I assume you don't have them in a matrix (I actually assume you don't know what a matrix is, but please don't get offended by this), you have them in separate arrays and you exactly know how many arrays you have (let's say 3). I also assume they all have the same length.

The idea is: for each available position, we check the three elements occupying that position in the three arrays and see if they are all true. What can we do with the result from this comparison? We can print it to screen, put it in another array, or whatever we fancy doing.

Let's start with the three arrays:

```
boolean[] foo = {true, true, false};
boolean[] bar = {true, false, false};
boolean[] baz = {true, false, false};
```

Ok. We can now create a fourth array to store our results.

```
boolean[] qux = new boolean[3];
```

or, even better:

```
boolean[] qux = new boolean[foo.length];
```

Let's start building our C-styled loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

If you are working with arrays, you probably already know how a *for* loop works: first statement will be executed as if it were written **before** the whole block of code within curly brackets; second statement gets checked as **first** instruction every time the block is executed and in case it fails the loop stops; third statement will be executed as **last** instruction every time the block gets executed.
And you probably already know that if an array has length `n`, the indexes for its elements will be
`0, [...], n-1`.
In case you didn't know these two things... Well, you're welcome.

So, what did I say we want to do with every available position? We want to compare the three elements in that position. So the for loop becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {

    if (foo[i] && bar[i] && baz[i]) {
        ...
    }

}
```

What we just added is this check: if the element at position `i` in array **foo** is a `true`, ***AND ALSO*** the element at position `i` in array **bar** is a `true`, ***AND ALSO*** the element at position `i` in array **baz** is a `true`... We do something.

We can for instance put the result in **qux**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {

    if (foo[i] && bar[i] && baz[i]) {

        qux[i] = true;

    } else {

        qux[i] = false;

    }

}
```

Note that the comparison itself evaluates to a boolean, and when its value is `true` we store a `true`; when `false` we store a `false`. So we can also write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {

    qux[i] = (foo[i] && bar[i] && baz[i]);

}
```

Grrrrreat, we achieved what we wanted to achieve! Do you also want to display such result? Let me introduce you the *enhanced for* loop:

```
for (boolean val : qux) {
    ...
}
```

Basically, being **qux** an array of booleans, it is a "container" of boolean values. This for statement says: for each of the elements making up **qux**... Do something.

So, let's use it to print these elements:

```
for (boolean val : qux) {

    System.out.println(val);

}
```

Method `println()`, in object `out`, static member of class `System` (don't worry if you don't understand all these terms, you will learn their meaning if you continue studying Java) displays on screen something. Technically, this "something" should be a String, but since Java knows how to make strings out of booleans, we don't have to worry too much when passing *val* to it.

Want to do everything within the first *for* and also print in a pretty way? Easy as pie:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {

    qux[i] = (foo[i] && bar[i] && baz[i]);

    System.out.println("At position " + i + " we have " + qux[i]);

}
```

So, how do we now check for all-false positions? We can use the bang (`!`), whose meaning is: take this boolean and consider its negation (`true` if it is `false` and `false` if it is `true`).
Using it, we can express this check: if the element at position `i` in array **foo** is a `false`, ***AND ALSO*** the element at position `i` in array **bar** is a `false`, ***AND ALSO*** the element at position `i` in array **baz** is a `false`... We do something.

So we would need a fifth array:

```
boolean[] norf = new boolean[foo.length];
```

And we would change our loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {

    qux[i] = (foo[i] && bar[i] && baz[i]);

    if (qux[i]) {

            System.out.println("At position " + i + " they are all true.");

    }

    norf[i] = (!foo[i] && !bar[i] && !baz[i]);

    if (norf[i]) {

            System.out.println("At position " + i + " they are all false.");

    }

}
```

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to wrap you arrays within another array, create a 2D matrix, for example...

```
boolean matrix[][] = {
    {true, true, false},
    {true, false, false},
    {true, false, false}
};
```

Then for each column, in each row, you want to check to see if the values match or not

```
boolean results[] = new boolean[3];
for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    Boolean value = null;
    boolean matches = true;
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        if (value == null) {
            value = matrix[row][col];
        } else if (matrix[row][col] != value) {
            matches = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    results[col] = matches;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
for (int col = 0; col < results.length; col++) {
    if (results[col]) {
        System.out.println(col);
    }
}
```

Which prints...

```
[true, false, true]
0
2
```

The reason for the `boolean results[]` array is because each column will either match (`true`) or it won't (`false`), it's just a matter of checking each element to determine which indices result in a `true` result